# In Hosted Enterprise Chef server -5NODES FREE

Tags: chef-infra, hosted

In hosted enterprise chef server , they have 5 nodes free for us . I dont understand what is meant by this 5nodes free. IF 5 NODES FREE MEANS they mentioning a nodes which we registered in chef server through workstation ah??

CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN THIS HOSTED ENTERPRISE CHEF SERVER FREE NODE?

Thanks in advance,
Indu

Comment: Why are you screaming?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

A node is any physical, virtual, or cloud machine that is configured to be maintained by a chef-client.

Five of such nodes (usually servers) of yours can be used with chef enterprise for free.

This is explained more in detail in the [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes.html)

Comment: Thanks , now i can add nodes in a hosted chef server .I ve tested by adding nodes through bootstrapping ,it gets adding more than 5nodes in a hosted enterprise chef server,WHICH MEANS WHAT THEY INDICATING FREE OF NODES MEANS??????????

Comment: Sorry, please stop writing in upper case, this is [interpreted as screaming](http://edtech2.boisestate.edu/mattarnetoj/502/netiquette.html) in the internet. Also your other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732752/hosted-enterprise-chef-server-5node-free) got down-voted because of this.

Comment: If you bootstrap the 6th machine, then this is the 6th node and the restriction will probably not allow to let that node register at the Chef server. (don't know exactly, how it is implemented)

Comment: It triggers an alert and then our sales people look at it. If it's an honest mistake, it is usually let alone. If you register like 500 nodes, we will hold the account and sales will contact you.